# Flutter Hive Box not found error on first run, but it works fine after I reload the app

Tags: flutter, persistence, flutter-hive

I have two Hive Boxes as below. I always face **this error** when I build the app for the **first time**.

> Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?

However, if I reload the app, it works perfectly fine.
Here is the code in my **main func** where I open the **hive boxes.**
I wonder what is causing that error. I don't want my user to restart the app after installing it for the first time.

```
void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    
      await Hive.initFlutter();
      await Hive.openBox("User");
      await Hive.openBox("dateData");
    
      runApp(const SplashPage());
    }
```

Comment: I have same issue when I restart my device in realease mode it throw exception and not run my app

Comment: I don't know if this fixes your problem, but I've always put my Hive initialization in a `FutureBuilder` along with all of the other async tasks that need to happen prior to loading my app.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`FutureBuilder` will do wonder for you,

***why it is better to use FutureBuilder for Hive?***

When we initialize Hive, it loads all data from the memory, and may take time, till then we must show some kind of animation/loader to user, otherwise your app look like it's freez.

**Example:**

```
Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Hive.openBox('box_name'),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                  child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
              );
            } else
              return Page1();
          } else {
            return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    )
```

Comment: thank you for the snippets. I did it with error handling and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize hive before using it [see this image to see how to do that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw7Vg.png)

Comment: may I know what `path_provider` is? I don't know how it works.

Comment: A Flutter plugin for finding commonly used locations on the filesystem. Supports Android, iOS, Linux, macOS and Windows. Not all methods are supported on all platforms.

https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it using `try{}catch(){}` error handling as shown below. the project was nearly due and I couldn't find any better solution but this works perfect. Here is the code.

```
void addData() async {
    try{ 
      Box<dynamic> data = Hive.box("boxName");
    }catch(error){
       await Hive.openBox("boxName");
       addData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue you described. I was using two Hive boxes, and on the app's initial run, data written to a box would return null when read. Subsequent builds functioned as expected.

No errors were reported, and the code appeared correct. After extensive debugging, I discovered the solution:

Hive boxes require **distinct** and **specified** **data types** when using **multiple boxes**. Different box names alone are insufficient and can lead to this peculiar error.

To illustrate, here's the corrected code:

```
void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    
      await Hive.initFlutter();
      await Hive.openBox<DataType1>("User");
      await Hive.openBox<DataType2>("dateData");
    
      runApp(const SplashPage());
    }
```